# Maven adding jars to war which are not present in dependency:tree

Tags: java, maven, jar, spring-boot, war

I've recently prepared spring-boot configuration to work properly on a standalone jetty.

I've encountered a strange behavior from maven. It adds jars to my .war archive which are not present in `mvn dependency:tree`. I've worked around the problem by adding this to my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But that's obviously an ugly solution.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pretius</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBootJettyExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-Boot jetty example app</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>spbj-example</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring-Boot jetty example app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ springBootJettyExample ---
[INFO] com.pretius:springBootJettyExample:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:runtime
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.746 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-05T09:36:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(Yes, there is *one* tomcat lib in the tree, but there are several added to .war)

Unwanted jars:

```
tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-jdbc-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-juli-8.0.26.jar
```

[Here's a link to the sample application.](http://pretius.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/springBootJettyExample.zip)

What is adding the `tomcat*` jars to my .war? How can I stop it doing so?

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: What you are saying is really weird. Please post your whole POM.

Comment: Added both files, though please notice the link to a sample application at the end of the question. You can download it and see for yourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when I run maven package this pom produces two war files one named "spbj-example.war" for running with

```
org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

and another one named "spbj-example.war.original".

You should use the second war which doesn't contain anything related to servers.
The first one contains a lib directory in which you have jar files to run a server like "jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar" and lots of others.

So most likey problem is related to your dirty "target" directory.
You should use

```
 mvn clean package/install
```

Comment: I've checked both wars and both contain "tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-jdbc-8.0.26.jar
tomcat-juli-8.0.26.jar" which are nowhere to be found in the dependency tree

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your target dir. I guess. Can you try running mvn "clean install" or "clean package" because I don't have those jars in my second war file.

Comment: Actually, `clean` has solved the problem for both .war files! Feel free to change your answer and I'll accept it.